# Save and Retrieve records using arrays vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to retrieve records from this array to my listview ?

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim countitems As Integer
    countitems = ListView2.Items.Count - 1
    ReDim valueArray(countitems, 5)
    Dim xarray = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To countitems
        For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
            valueArray(xarray, 0) = Item.Text
            valueArray(xarray, 1) = Item.SubItems(1).Text
            valueArray(xarray, 2) = Item.SubItems(2).Text
            valueArray(xarray, 3) = Item.SubItems(3).Text
            valueArray(xarray, 4) = Item.SubItems(4).Text
            valueArray(xarray, 5) = Item.SubItems(5).Text
            i += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking... In your sample, "i" and "xarray" are useless variables. I assume you would want to remove the For i and increment xarray instead.

Comment: I have a ListView control set up in details mode, and on a button press I would like to retrieve all column values from that row in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all record in the listview, you would look at something like this.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim countitems As Integer
    countitems = ListView2.Items.Count - 1
    ReDim valueArray(countitems, 5)
    Dim xarray = 0

    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        valueArray(xarray, 0) = Item.Text
        valueArray(xarray, 1) = Item.SubItems(1).Text
        valueArray(xarray, 2) = Item.SubItems(2).Text
        valueArray(xarray, 3) = Item.SubItems(3).Text
        valueArray(xarray, 4) = Item.SubItems(4).Text
        valueArray(xarray, 5) = Item.SubItems(5).Text
        xarray += 1
    Next

End Sub
```